# How to insert an image using a class (dirname and filepath issue)

Tags: php

I have a method in a class I would like to use in order to show an image in a page that could be placed in any directory.

Basically, the class file would be at the root directory and the class would look like this:

```
class A{
    function showImage(){
        echo '<img src="img/file.jpg">';
    }
}
```

Problems occur when I call the method in a page which is in a subdirectory.
For example, if I use `showImage()` in 'subdir/mypage.php', then the image link is broken.

I have looked into `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `dirname(__FILE__)` but I coud not find the right mix to get the right image path that could be used in order to show the image from any directory.

What function should I used in the class to get the file path dynamically that would depending on the directory where I am calling `showImage()`?

Many thanks

Comment: You can define a global `$base_url` variable. Such that `$base_url="www.mysite.com/"` then you can use this base url anywhere. like `echo '<img src="<?php echo $base_url.'img/file.jpg' ?>">'`. It will be independent of any sub directories etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A{
    function showImage($link){
        $link = str_replace('/home/public', '', $link);
        echo '<img src="' . $link . '">';
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$a->showImage(getcwd().'/img/file.jpg');
```

The `getcwd()` will get the directory, then remove the first absolute path to your public folder in the function.

Example case:

- test.php is placed in /home/public/images/{test.php}
- class.php is placed in /home/public/{class.php}

test.php does:

```
$a->showImage(getcwd().'/img/file.jpg');
```

What it'll send to class.php is:

```
$a->showImage('/home/public/images/img/file.jpg');
```

Then in your function it'll remove `/home/public` and show this link:

```
<img src="/images/img/file.jpg">
```

---

### MY BAD

I didn't read the answer right. Here's the solution you're looking for:

```
class A{
    function showImage(){
        $root = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
        echo '<img src="' . $root . 'img/file.jpg">';
    }
}
```